# exim configuration and AWS SES

Tags: exim, amazon-ses

I am trying to configure exim on a CentOS instance in EC2 to use AWS SES as a relay SMTP server.
I configure it using [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-email-exim.html) guide. The SES account is currently in sandbox mode, and I have verified two addresses, the sender and the recipient.

When trying to send a test mail as suggested in the guide, I get the following error:

> SMTP error from remote mail server after end of data: 554 Message rejected: Email address is not verified. The following identities failed the check in region EU-CENTRAL-1: root@hostname

Also, in the output I see the following line:

> SMTP>> MAIL FROM:root@hostname SIZE=1369 AUTH=root@hostname

From which I assume that although I have set "From" to be a verified address, exim still uses my username@hostname as Mail From, which of course is not verified in SES.
Could not understand from exim documentation how to change it.

Any ideas how to make it work while staying in the sandbox mode in SES?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/548826/exim-change-sender-address-when-sending-mails-out-of-local-network/548844)

Added the following line to exim configuration file:

> begin rewrite
> ^root@hostname authenticated_email@address.com SFfrs

And then the root@hostname is replaced with authenticated_email@address.com as expected